# Why is replication stopped?

Tags: mysql, replication

Got the following nagios alert this morning for our MySQL replica:

> 14:49 PROBLEM: mysql2/MySQL replication check is CRITICAL, 10.1.0.133 is 72870 seconds behind, Aug 09, 21:49 UTC

When I look at `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on the replica, the places I normally look at are fine:

```
Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
Seconds_Behind_Master: 73698
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
Last_IO_Errno: 0
Last_SQL_Errno: 0
```

Where else should I be looking to diagnose and fix replication?

Comment: As long as Exec_Master_Log_Pos is increasing, you are processing and just behind.  Is it increasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Seconds_Behind_Master** is the difference between the timestamps a statement was most recently downloaded by the IO_THREAD and when it was most recently executed.

I'd highly recommend `pt-heartbeat` for monitoring your replication status.

> pt-heartbeat is a two-part MySQL and PostgreSQL replication delay
>   monitoring system that measures delay by looking at actual replicated
>   data. This avoids reliance on the replication mechanism itself, which
>   is unreliable. (For example, SHOW SLAVE STATUS on MySQL).

Source: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-heartbeat.html

Answer (score 1):

Has anything been written to the Master in the last 72K seconds (about a day)?

Sometimes this helps:

```
STOP SLAVE;
START SLAVE;
```

I have seen the need for this on and off over the last decade; never figured out why it might be needed.

Another mystery is that the Seconds_behind_master sometimes mysteriously decides to flap between zero and some large value.  Eventually that problem clears itself up.

Comment: I'm certain something has been written. There's about 200 databases total across a variety of projects. Restarting the slave seems... unreliable.

Comment: As far as i know the `Seconds_Behind_Master` are the difference between the slave current time and the event time stamp of binary log. The event time stamp could be different of commit time.  So `Seconds_Behind_Master`  is not accurate measurement of delay between master and slave.

Comment: In the case of a long-running query (eg, `ALTER` of big table), the Master's "time" is when the `ALTER` _started_ on the Master.